# Why are these typedefs both public and private?

Tags: c++

I'm looking in the libstdc++ source code for stack, and it shows the same type being typedef'd twice:

```
  template<typename _Tp, typename _Sequence = deque<_Tp> >
    class stack
    {
      // concept requirements
      typedef typename _Sequence::value_type _Sequence_value_type;

      ...

    public:
      typedef typename _Sequence::value_type                value_type;
```

What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: The private interface most likely has a different naming convention. And the standard mandates a public `value_type` member.

Comment: Guessing without knowing the code: Maybe they want to have all public interfaces at the end, but refer to a shorter name in their private interfaces ...